# Box.com api redirect URL to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, box-api

I'm trying to do some initial testing in my local environment with box.com api.  I've registered the api key and I'd like to put a localhost url in redirect uri form field but it seems like it only allows https (which I don't have in localhost).  Message returned:

```
OAuth2 redirect URL must specify a valid URL and must not be http://
```

Comment: Looks like I can add it to the URL directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement for the https is a good thing. While you are still in dev it would still be an active auth token transmitted in plain text if sent to http:// which someone could grab and use to mess with your box.net account.

You are going to need to generate a self signed certificate and install that locally to allow for this to work.

[How can I create a self-signed cert for localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost)

Another option to further enhance this would be to actually buy the SSL that you are going to need for this project when it goes live and use a local dns redirect via your hosts file to load the domain off your local dev machine as opposed to the live server.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm in a rails environment and I'm using omniauth as well.  I somewhat agree with what you are saying but it seems like all other oauth2 providers I use (google, facebook, etc) allow for a localhost pattern in the response uri.

Comment: Went with this...I was actually able to quickly get this up and running since I'm using thin for rails.  To start in ssl mode it's as simple as:  thin start --ssl

Comment: pleas refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024693/why-do-i-get-a-redirect-uri-mismatch-when-trying-to-log-into-box

Answer (score 1):

Box has updated itself to allow `localhost` to be `http://`. For other URIs, you need `https://`