# Why do I get a redirect URI mismatch when trying to log into Box?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, oauth-2.0, box-api

When using the [Box SDK for iOS](https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2) to do OAuth, I am shown a webpage with this error:

[image]

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> response_type=code
>   redirect_uri=boxsdk-our4iypzazstfpx8j70e8tlc3eyn9c4l://boxsdkoauth2redirect
>   state=ok client_id=our4iypzazstfpx8j70e8tlc3eyn9c4l

I used the code that they suggested:

```
[self
    presentViewController:[[BoxAuthorizationViewController alloc]
        initWithAuthorizationURL:[[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session authorizeURL]
        redirectURI:nil
    ]
    animated:YES
    completion:nil
];
```

My client ID and client secret are set prior to this. In my info.plist file, I have *boxsdk-our4iypzazstfpx8j70e8tlc3eyn9c4l* as a URL scheme. The only instruction I could not follow is:

> Note: When setting up your service on Box, leave the OAuth2 reditrect
>   URI blank. The SDK will provide a custom redirect URI when issuing
>   OAuth2 calls; doing so requires that no redirect URI be set in your
>   service settings.

When I attempt to leave the redirect URI blank and save the form in the developer console, I get the this error:

> OAuth2 redirect URL must specify a valid URL and must not be http://

So I am forced to input something. I have inputted "https://mydomain.com" (with my real domain). I modified the iOS code to pass that URI into the BoxAuthorizationViewController, but I still get the same error webpage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, this was a mistake in our documentation. It should work if you enter `boxsdk-YOUR_CLIENT_ID://boxsdkoauth2redirect` into the developer console for your redirect_uri, replacing YOUR_CLIENT_ID with your actual client ID.

Comment: I use this format in the field, but only works on iOS not Android. And I can't leave the field blank.

Comment: @greg, I did same process but its doesn't worked for me. I set redirect_uri - https://api.box.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id= MY_CLIENT_ID&state=ok&redirect_uri=boxsdk-MY_CLIENT_ID%3A%2F%2Fboxsdkoauth2redirect.   Please suggest...

Comment: @greg, And after almost one year, mistake is still in your documentation:
https://developers.box.com/authentication-in-your-ios-app/

Comment: Sorry @FarhadMalekpour, this must've fallen through the cracks. We'll soon be releasing a vastly improved iOS SDK which should make the authentication process a lot simpler and have much better documentation.

Comment: @Greg could you call people or mail them to create a clear example. I'm working for 3 days to make this redirect_uri going. Thanks for you answer it possibly saved my countless hours.