# SSL certificate for localhost

Tags: asp.net, ssl

I want use SSL (trial) from geotrust in my sample asp.net application localhost. But when I give common name 'localhost', the geotrust certificate gives error 'Common Name does not contain fully qualified domain name.' So what should I do to accomplish this?

Comment: For localhost you made a self signed certificate and work with that one.

Comment: Ok. After creating self signed certificate, how do I link with asp url i.e. localhost:2013?

Comment: You need to run a local iis that can support ssl (not the webserver that come with vs) and connect to https://

Comment: here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost

Comment: Why do you think you need to run SSL within the localhost?

Comment: I have to apply SSL on the live server, but first I want to apply it locally and test it for the specific pages.

Comment: Check similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037510/secure-websocket-wss-with-https-localhost-ssl-certificate/40107095#40107095