# Secure WebSocket (WSS) with HTTPS localhost SSL certificate?

Tags: android, ssl, https, websocket

I am a little new to this whole WebSocket and SSL certificate.

So I have created my own WebSocket server on Android side and the website is the client. I was able to make it work with regular WebSocket `(ws://)` but not secure WebSocket `(wss://)` due to the fact that it requires SSL certificate.

My question is how can I get a SSL certificate? From what I've read, SSL certificate is based on a domain. I need it for localhost.  I need it for something like this address:

```
wss://localhost:8080/ws/main
```

How can I go about getting a SSL certificate that will work with `localhost`.

Thank you for your time!

====================== EDIT =====================

Reason why I am doing this: 
I have a Bluetooth service in my Android application that will be getting data from connected health bluetooth devices like Weight Scale and Blood Pressure machine.  I have this part implemented already and I want to take this data and pass it to a website. WebSocket seemed easier because the user will have my application open and when they do their weight, it would automatically fill the field on the website with the weight from the Weight Scale.  I hope I am making this clear.

To do this, I need to have a way to pass the weight or blood pressure values from Java (Android) to the website that loads within a WebView.  So I thought WebSocket would the easiest way.

Please tell me if you think there is an easier way.

Also, I've already tried self-signed certificate and I get the following error:

```
I/X509Util: Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

OR

```
Exception=javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Error occured in delegated task:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Having an open port on an Android device is a risky proposition from a security standpoint. Beyond that, please explain how a `localhost` Web socket is being used by a "website". Is this Web server also hosted on the Android device? If it is a Web server hosted elsewhere, I do not see how it can use a Web socket that is only available via `localhost`. With respect to SSL and `localhost`, that's not possible AFAIK.

Comment: The websocket server is within the Android application and I am loading the the websocket client (the website) in a webview within the same application. That is why it is `localhost`.  This implementation works with regular websockets and I am able to send the data. I know the logic isn't the issue. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am unclear why you are using WebSockets in the first place, given that there are more efficient and secure options for having the on-device Web app communicate back to your Java code. SSL would seem to be pointless, given that the packets are not leaving your device. Regardless, other than perhaps a self-signed SSL cert, I don't know of any way to SSL encrypt `localhost`.

Comment: @CommonsWare please see my edit on the post. I've explained why I do this.  Thanks again!!

Comment: "Please tell me if you think there is an easier way" -- `addJavascriptInterface()` on `WebView`.

Comment: But how can `JavascriptInterface()` work here? I do not have the website code in my `assets`. It is an actual website I am loading.  Like `webView.loadUrl("https://myurl.com");`. Please tell me if I am missing something.  Thanks

Comment: Well, among other things, you are missing offline access. As it stands, your implementation will only work if the device has an Internet connection. Regardless, there's still nothing stopping you from using `addJavascriptInterface()`.

Comment: I've covered offline access where user will see an activity where bluetooth data will come in and save to local SQLite DB and when connected next time, it will send via WebSocket as a large JSON object.  And If i understand you correctly, I can still use `addJavascriptInterface()` even if the website code is not in my Android project? I didn't know that was a possibility

Comment: "I didn't know that was a possibility" -- it is. It is unusual, because usually the point of having a Web site is for it to *not* be in an Android app, but rather be used by regular Web browsers. In your case, you have a dependency upon the app anyway, as something has to have the WebSocket.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar problem, our solution was to register a subdomain to one of our domains with an A record to 127.0.0.1 and get a certificate for that domain.

- local.example.com -> A record to 127.0.0.1
- SSL certificate requested for local.example.com

I'm afraid this answer is too late for you however, it can be helpful for others finding this article.