# Enabling SSL on localhost IIS

Tags: ssl, https, localhost, ssl-certificate

I run localhost on my Windows 8.1 (Bootcamp on Mac) and need to enable ssl.

I have already default server certificates on 127.0.0.1 and localhost.
I have the localhost one assigned to my websites on port 443.

https still returns security error so I need to work on http

My websites run on 44300 port (eg. localhost:44300)
I tried to bind the certificate to 44300, still it didn't work.

How to make my locahost to work with https? Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT

The certificate is issued by localhost and is within Trusted Root Certification Authorities:

[image]

Btw I followed this thread to issue the certificate for my website: [Enable SSL in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183773/enable-ssl-in-visual-studio)

Comment: What is the contents of your certificate, i.e. is it even valid for the URL you use it?

Comment: @Steffen I believe they are built-in certificates as they were already there after I installed windows

Comment: Which does not say anything about the contents of the certificates. Maybe they are simply not suitable for what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok, so what I'm supposed to do @Steffen? I added self-signed certificate and it didn't work either. In other words - how can I check whether self-signed or built-in certificate is suitable for what I'm doing or not?

Comment: The certificate must match the hostname of the URL. Browser usually let you look into the certificate if you add it as trusted.

Comment: @Steffen it matches the hostname which is localhost

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: same is in firefox though. I can add an exception but still it treats the connection as unsecure

Comment: I've created for testing a self-signed certificate for localhost and successfully use it as trusted certificate in Chrome and Firefox. Which means you do something different but without knowing what you actually do it is hard to help. Chrome has usually more detailed error messages than just "security error", so maybe you could add more details to your question.

Comment: @Steffen I have added imgs to inllustrate what I have

Comment: Chrome says clearly that the certificate is untrusted.  What did you do to make the certificate trusted? Any certificates not issued by a public CA known to the browser have no implicit trust, i.e. the user must manuelly add them as trusted. Note that settings on the server side do not make it trusted, it has to be done on the client side (browser).

Comment: @Steffen I followed instructions in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183773/enable-ssl-in-visual-studio I have edited my post to include the certificate I currently have above

Comment: I have no idea why it took you 3 years to provide the necessary information but based on this it is a duplicate of other question, i.e. you simply did not add this certificate as trusted to the browser and by default it will not trust self-signed certificates.

Comment: @Steffen I did say I added it to trusted, not sure why you're implying I did not? I just worked 3 years on browser's exception on localhost, it's doable...

Comment: The error message clearly says it is not trusted. I'm not really sure what image should prove that the certificate is trusted - there is one where the certificate is issued to nothing (valid from 22/10/2018) and one where it is issued to localhost (valid from 24/10/2018). These are clearly different certificates. I have no idea what certificate is served by your IIS and which certificate is trusted by your browser - likely different ones.

Comment: @Steffen, the last certificate. See my comment below the first answer. Thanks

Comment: This comment says that you've actually did not properly import the certificate as trusted first - and after you did this it worked with Chrome. As for you new problem with Firefox: it has a separate certificate store and you need to import it there as trusted too.

Answer (score 40):

It is probably because it is not installed in `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`.

[image]

Solve this by starting `mmc.exe`.

Then go to:

File -> Add or Remove Snap-ins -> Certificates -> Add -> Computer account -> Local computer

Expand the `Personal` folder and you will see your `localhost` certificate:

[image]

Copy this into `Trusted Root Certification Authorities - Certificates`

The final step is to open `Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager` or simply `inetmgr.exe`. From there go to your site, select `Bindings...` and `Add...` or `Edit...`. Set `https` and select your certificate from the drop down.

[image]

Your certificate is now trusted:

[image]

Original answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790088/3850405

Comment: @nickornotto issued to needs to be localhost

Comment: I redid the certificate and it is issues by localhost, see my edited post

Comment: @nickornotto Is the certificate really in Local computer - Trusted Root Certification Authorities? It won't work with Current User - Trusted Root Certification Authorities. Also click the lock icon in your browser and view what certificate is being sent. If you follow my link to original answer you will get it right.

Comment: ok, I have now run it in Chrome and it works! In Firefox though it doesn't work even though I cleaned cookies. But it works in MS Explorer too so the certificate is fine. Thanks for help

Comment: @nickornotto No problem! Please mark the answer as the correct solution if it helped you solve it.

Comment: @nickornotto can't work for me,,   my website (localhost) still not secure (Invalid Certifiicate),, any suggestion for me?

Comment: I couldn't find `inetmgr` but the first step still resolved my problem. Would love to see a `powershell` or batch equivalent! Maybe another day, I've got going on to tackle.

Answer (score 8):

Try to install **[Microsoft IIS Administration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4sP9.png)** from https://manage.iis.net/get
it will create a certification for your local server 
then use https://manage.iis.net/connect , get an Access Token and connect it 
check your localhost on https https://localhost

Comment: Company with 4 developers here… you saved us today, thank you! 

Comment: Apparently this site no longer exists :(