# Is it possible to run Blazor WASM project locally on IIS without having to publish it?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm building a Blazor WASM app that needs to run in the same domain as the web API project that already exists. So if the API runs on https://localhost the Blazor App needs to be in https://localhost/app.

Now I don't have an issue setting this up when I publish the Blazor App, but I don't want to have to publish it every time I make a code change and I also need to be able to debug.

Ideally in local machine dev environment the Blazor app would run on IIS at a specific domain, such as https://localhost/app and not require a publish while at the same time being able to debug via visual studio debugger if necessary. Is this setup possible and what do I need to do to get there?

Answer (score 0):

In `Visual Studio` set a launch profile on the `Blazor WASM` application to use IIS. You can then set the `App URL` to point to `https://localhost/app`. Also tick `Launch Browser` if not ticked. Usually you will also have to set the Environment variables to `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

**Navigation:**

Right click project -> Properties (Alt + Enter) -> (Left side) Select Debug -> `Open debug launch profiles UI` -> Create a new profile (top left)

[image]

For creating `HTTPS` trusted `localhost` you can just follow the answers here: [Enabling SSL on localhost IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240014/enabling-ssl-on-localhost-iis)