# How to create HTTPS cert for ExpressJS app?

Tags: node.js, linux, express, ssl, ca

This is how I generate a self-signed certificate, following this [guide](http://blog.mgechev.com/2014/02/19/create-https-tls-ssl-application-with-express-nodejs/):

```
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

In my code, in bin/www:

```
 var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert.pem'),
  passphrase: 'xxxx'
};
```

I will get a warning on Chrome:

> Your connection is not private

[image]

If I use it over an iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://127.0.1.1:3030/" width="100%" height="900" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

Then I will get this error on Chrome:

> GET https://127.0.1.1:3030/ net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

How can I create the certificate properly without having these warning and error?

**Notes:**

There is accepted answer from that suggestion.Also most of the answers are for Windows. I am on Linux/ Ubuntu/ Arch.

Comment: Does the certificate include the port 3030 for the domain?

Comment: Check this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a self-signed cert for localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost)

Comment: @hjpotter92 should I include the port 3030 in? the process never ask me to put in the address when creating the cert at all.