# How to setup a self-signed certificate for iis but without a hostname

Tags: iis, https, ssl-certificate, single-sign-on, identityserver3

How to setup a self-signed certificate for iis but without a hostname.
I'm building a website for enterprise, it's a local lan website, But Since I want to use identity server for SSO, I need to bind the site to https.
I've created a self-signed certificate, and bind to the website, But when I browse to this site, all the browsers said this site is not secure, so the identity server didn't work.
After searching a lot on the web, it seems the site need a hostname to make the certificate work. But it's an enterprise internal website, I don't think it can be bound to a hostname.
I don't know how to make https work normally. please help!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a self-signed cert for localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost)

Comment: You completely get it the wrong way. A host name won't help. Self-signed certificates are by design not trusted by anyone. If you are building an enterprise site, ask the network administrator how to enroll a valid certificate.

Comment: Thank you, really helpful, I finally understand this certificate thing now....