# how to make a https request in python 3

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to download a file from my server using the https protocol. How should I go about doing this?
This is my basic code with http

```
response=requests.get('http://url',stream='True')

handle=open('dest_file.txt','wb')
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
        handle.write(chunk)

handle.close()
```

can the requests module be used for https as well?

Comment: Do you want an actual `file` or a webpage? I guess if you want a file you will have to have a service on your server to send the data via `http`

Comment: yes, I want a text file which is on my server.

Comment: via http I am able to access the contents of the file, but I am not able to make a connection using https

Comment: Maybe change the tile to reflect the question. `How to FTP via HTTPS?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

```py
response=requests.get('https://url', stream='True', verify='your certificate.crt')

handle=open('dest_file.txt','wb')
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
        handle.write(chunk)

handle.close()
```

Comment: Where can I get SSL certificates?

Comment: Your server should place SSL certificate using the same certificate file. If you want to generate a simple certificate you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost/32169444#32169444

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful!