# Facebook Login Error on PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Whenever i tried to login with facebook i'm getting the following error.

> Insecure login Blocked. You cant get access token or log in to this app from insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

This code is in my localhost.

And this the url i'm using `http://localhost/php-facebook-login/login.php` same url only i have given in the facebook app configuration page.

Please help me to rectify this issues.

Thank you.

Comment: change it to https?

Comment: how to change localhost url into _https_

Comment: start your server with https...

Comment: Search for [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost) first..

Comment: @Guna what software are you using to run PHP on your localhost?

Comment: I'm using xampp

Answer (score -1):

Since March 2018 Facebook requires redirect URIs to be served using HTTPS by default. The toggle is called "Enforce HTTPS". See Facebook's manual for more details [Facebook Login Security](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security)

As the commenters pointed out the redirect will work even for localhost. But I am not sure if Facebook will accept a self signed certificate.

Comment: It can work if you have a localhost certificate, It was working 2 months ago

Comment: thank you markus. Is there anyway to test the facebook login instead of live server.

Comment: @proofzy how to get certification for my localhost please tell me

Comment: We usually set up a dedicated testing environment, with their own domains and certificates. Perhaps you'll find some best practices or advices in Facbook's documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/testing-your-login-flow

Comment: _“Facebook login will only work, if the redirect URL is available from the internet”_ - absolute nonsense. The redirect happens inside the user’s browser, therefor it also only needs to work there for your local testing.

Comment: Corrected the answer