# HTTPS server for Windows and Node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, https

Asking here because I have scoured the web and haven't found a tutorial that is simple enough for me to understand. I am trying to create a local web server with https so that I can access the camera stream from my phone. For my web server I am using Node.js on a windows machine. I am accessing my web server from my phone using my computers local IP address. I don't have a domain name. I'm not trying to make a fully fledged website, just a demo for a hackathon.

I have tried LetsEncrypt but during the setup for [win-acme](https://github.com/PKISharp/win-acme), it asks for stuff like what kind of certificate I want to create and what is the web root, and I'm not sure what to put there (localhost? my ip address?). When I try to follow the instructions on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost), I tried the command

`New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "localhost" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"`

but I don't know where the `.key` and `.crt` files went. Can anybody provide a simple and easy to understand tutorial on what to do? This is my second time running into this problem and it seems like nobody around me knows how to solve it either.

Comment: [This one is rather good.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) Although for `NGINX`. The gist works though. Sorry. Perhaps off. But you might get the infos you need to run `win-acme`.

Comment: @AjAX. thing is...I don't have a domain name, and certbot doesn't work on windows. I'm not trying to get a fully fledged website, just a demo for a hackathon

Comment: Then use the `IP-address`.

Comment: @AjAX. I tried that actually. It told me "Error creating new authz :: Issuance for IP addresses not supported"

Comment: Whoops. [Have you tried another client?](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/)

Comment: I did try acme.sh on the windows linux subsystem, but I didn't know what to put when it asked for a "web root"

Comment: Sorry wrong tutorial. [Webroot is the `directory` your `server` is serving from.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-debian-8)

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm stuck in the same place.

Comment: @Rthomas529 it doesn't seem like there is an easy way for creating CA certificates for websites without a domain name. I just needed this project for a hackathon, so I ended up just using [this npm package](https://github.com/gkovacs/self-signed-https) and even though the certificate is expired, when chrome sent me to the warning page I just clicked "continue anyways" to get to my website. Not sure if this method still works though