# How to GET json Data using curl in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, curl

I have been trying to use this paystack api

```
curl "https://api.paystack.co/bank" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer SECRET_KEY" 
-X GET
```

but don't know how to go about using using curl which am not really familiar with.

I have tried working my way around it but i get stuck all the time.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Bank_details extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $url = "https://api.paystack.co/bank";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt(
          $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Authorization: Bearer SECRET_KEY']
        );
        $request = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump(json_decode($request));
    }

}
```

with these lines, i am displayed with a message like so:

```
C:\wamp64\www\main_dir\application\controllers\Bank_details.php:22:null
```

Comment: using correct `SECRET_KEY` ?

Comment: i've got none @devpro.

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`?  Should it be a GET?

Comment: pass the correct `SECRET_KEY` it will work

Comment: just did and its not working @devpro

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` remove this it will work as you are not using post data

Comment: got this @devpro C:\wamp64\www\main_dir\application\controllers\Bank_details.php:22:null

Comment: what is line 22, as i am getting the result

Comment: var_dump(json_decode($request)); is in line 22

Comment: if you are getting the result, you can as well share with me your lines so i could know what am doing wrong @devpro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195994/discussion-between-devpro-and-courage).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a self-signed cert for localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed providing  JSON content type

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
     array('Content-Type:application/json',)
  );
```

Comment: it was SSL issue