# Communication problem with Web Service in localhost via SSL

Tags: web-services, ssl, iis, localhost

I have created a certificate with Powershell:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "localhost" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

I have copied the certificate to trusted root certification authorities

I have enabled certificate binding in IIS

Now if I access localhost from chrome I see the ssl connection correctly

[image: IIS SSL]

however, if I start the connection from the web application I get the following error:

```
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Request text: https://localhost/webservice/api/ImboundCall/?Telephone=5551234
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. 
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

even with Postman same message

Comment: " trusted root certification authorities" of which account? If you copied to your own account's, it won't work because web apps on IIS can only read machine account's.

Comment: in machine account, i followed all this step https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost/48790088#48790088

Comment: Then tell us more about that web application, such as what account is used as application pool identity to run this web app.

Comment: The web application is not in localhost but it is a VoIP System Management Console that interfaces with my web service through a link to localhost

Comment: Then you need some help from the software manual or documentation to learn how it verifies the certificate.

Comment: they told me to write on stackoverflow because this is enough for them