# Self-signed root certificate is still not valid

Tags: localhost, ssl-certificate

I want to test my website in Mac with localhost.

I followed [this step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32169444/702977) to generate `localhost.crt` and `localhost.key`. Then, I double-clicked `localhost.crt` to insert it in `System` of `Keychains` and then set `Always Trust`.

Then, I launched the website in Chrome. I still see `Your connection to this site is not secure` and `Certificate (Invalid)`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html You can learn more.

Comment: @Rob I get your point, but could you just stop commenting the same thing on all my SO questions? Otherwise, I will flag that...

Comment: Didn't notice it was all you. It's just an auto-generated list of vote closures in the list given to me.

Comment: @Rob well, it is me...

Comment: Then you should fix that cause it's up for closure for that reason.

Comment: Rob working overtime.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that the browser didn’t accept the certificate and can happen when you got the wrong domain, the certificate expired (not your case) or the browser doesn't recognize the certificate authority from where the certificate came from (most likely that's the case).

---

When creating a self signed SSL certificate, the browser (Firefox) can also return

> Invalid Certification Authority

And the Chrome can say

> Not secure

This is fine since one uses a self-signed certificate.