# Generate self-signed certificates in Windows

Tags: ssl-certificate

I want to generate a self-signed SSL certificate in Windows and use it with my website for IE and Edge.

Two files `.pvk` and `.cer` needs to be inserted into the code of my website.

I followed [this page](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/generating-self-signed-certificates-on-windows-7812a600c2d8), run the following commands, generated a `powershellcert.pfx`

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname company.co.nz

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String ‘password1234’ -Force -AsPlainText

$path = ‘cert:\localMachine\my\’ + $cert.thumbprint

Export-PfxCertificate -cert $path -FilePath c:\junk\certificate\powershellcert.pfx -Password $pwd
```

Does anyone know how to generate `.pvk` and `.cer`?

**Edit 1:**

I downloaded PVKConverter, and run `PVKConverter.exe -i powershellcert -o pvk -d "password1234"`, there is only one file `pvk_1.cer` generated.

Does anyone know how I could generate `.pvk` as well?

Answer (score 0):

To generate `.pvk` and `.cer` files from the content of your `.pfx` file, use Microsoft's `PVKConverter` tool, downloadable from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40812

Comment: Thank you... Please see my `Edit 1` in OP. Do you know how to generate `.pvk` as well?

Answer (score 0):

A well-known service for providing free SSL certificates is [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Using [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/), you can just run the following command to generate a certificate in the folder you want them to be stored

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mykey.key -out mycert.pem
```

(-x509 means x509 protocol; -days 365 for 1 year; -newkey is to generate a new key; rsa:2048 is to use the 2,048-bit RSA algorithm; -keyout is the kocation to place the key; -out is the location to place the certificate)

To note that [you might still get "Not secure", "Invalid Certification Authority" warnings because they are self signed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60586403/5675325).

---

To install openssl on Windows go to [openssl Wiki Binaries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries), then to the [first link in the table](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), scroll down and you'll find installers for Windows, both 64 and 32 bits versions. Choose the version depending on your system, download and install.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way To Generate new SSL Certificate
Open Powershell as administrator run the below command

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation C:\certificates -DnsName "Instance_Name" -FriendlyName "My First Next JSS APP" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

To check if the self signed certificate is generated goto run and type mmc
File>Add/Remove Snap
Select Certificate click OK
Now, check the certificate in Personal and Trusted Root Certification Authorities
if not present in anyone copy and paste