# how to fix net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR?

Tags: reactjs

This is the code i am working with in visual studio.

```
componentDidMount(){
         axios.get('https://localhost:9090/teams/get/all')
         .then(response=>{
             console.log(response)
             this.setState({posts:response.data})
         })

         .catch(error=>{
             console.log(error)
         })
     }
```

xhr.js:178 GET https://localhost:9090/teams/get/all net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

This one is the error i am getting everytime.

Comment: `localhost` by default runs on `http`, not `https`

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a self signed SSL certificate (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost))

... But you're most probably better off with accessing `http://localhost:9090/teams/get/all` (note the absence of s).