# Chrome uses different localhost SSL certificate than Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-chrome, asp.net-core, ssl

VS 2019 16.5.0 Preview 5
Windows 10
Chrome Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I Googled this and am unable to find an answer.

I am trying to run a simple asp.net core MVC app with TLS on localhost.

What I did is I created a new project then in the project settings I enabled SSL and the URL I got I copied as App URL
[image]
[image]

App starts properly and TLS CA is not trusted? I followed the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790088/4950215 and I added the certificated Located in `Personal/Certificates` folder to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities - Certificates` manage computer certificates now showed that the CA is trusted.

I reloaded the app and I saw that the localhost SSL certificate used by Chrome is different than the one registered on my computer, and therefore the CA is still not trusted.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just to mention this, I am showing the certificate from the Personal folder, but that certificate is 1:1 with the one from the Trusted root folder. https://i.imgur.com/U0kXut5.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the issue:

[image]

Basically, for whatever reason, I had a localhost installed on my `LocalComputer` store certificates. This made me think that Visual Studio created it, in reality VS creates certificates in the `CurrentUser` store, as [visible by the open code in the dotnet repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6cc9f6f130af4ed0e7f321b144265cfbcec0ceee/src/Tools/dotnet-dev-certs/src/Program.cs).
Typically the procedure, for generating and TLS certificate by VS, is expected to go as such:

1. A .NET Project is marked as HTTPS, and you try to run it.
2. VS checks if a certificate is present in the `CurrentUser` store, asks to create one if it's not
3. User clicks YES, to creating a certificate, initially the certificate is installed in the `CurrentUser/Personal/Certificates store`
4. VS then sees that you do not have a localhost certificate in `CurrentUser/TrustedRootCA/Certificates`, and makes a prompt to ask you if  you would like to install one, you click YES - everything  is done.

Now if for some reason you are like me... and your `CurrentUser/Trusted Root Certification Authority/Certificates` is read only. Then you end up on the following line of the code:

```
           case EnsureCertificateResult.FailedToTrustTheCertificate:
                reporter.Warn("There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate.");
```

Because well step 4 failed...

To mitigate this:

1. Open the `CurrentUser` and `LocalComputer` stores. You can do that by following this [microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in), or just type `certlm.msc` and `certmgr.msc` in the Start.
2. Right click Export on the localhost certificate in `CurrentUser` store and export it as with the default options
3. Try importing the same certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates folder of the `CurrentUser` store.
4. If step 3 failed,which it should have because you wouldn't be in this predicament otherwise, import your certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates folder of the `LocalComputer` store.

Now everything should work. Hopefully you wouldn't have spent 6 hours on this, like I did.

Comment: This was my issue post windows update. This fixed it. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I followed your steps and it worked but not right away. I did enter "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" then closed all VS instances and restarted it and then it worked. It was probably restarting VS that got it working. So for other ppl with the same issue => restart VS afterward. Thanks again

Answer (score 18):

In my case this worked:

1. Clean the old certificate and generate a new trusted one. Run the commands listed below:

   dotnet dev-certs https --clean

   dotnet dev-certs https --trust
2. Go to %APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets and delete all of the directories
3. Re-run the application. It should now run with no SSL errors

source: https://joeblogs.technology/2021/11/neterr_cert_date_invalid/

Comment: This worked for me, but you have to restart Visual Studio after doing these steps.

Comment: likewise @Jeff .

Comment: This is the way, though you only have to delete the folder relating to the app you are working on.

THANK YOU @dotnetcoder - the folder deletion step was the one that was missing for me.