# When integrating adobe creative SDK into a web app I get: {"error":"invalid_credentials"}

Tags: javascript, web, adobecreativesdk

I have followed the [Web: Getting Started Samples](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/web-getting-started-samples). When the function `AdobeCreativeSDK.init` is called it invoke [`https://adobeid-na1.services.adobe.com/ims/check/v4/token`](https://adobeid-na1.services.adobe.com/ims/check/v4/token) first with request method OPTIONS and then with request method POST, both returning status code 200 OK. The response to the POST request returns `{"error":"invalid_credentials"}` and I do not know why and how to solve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add code... Your question is useless at this moment. Obfuscate your credentials, but add code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tschallacka it is simply the code from the Web: Getting Started Samples as is.

Comment: Still, read the how to ask a good question part in the faq here. Always ppst a code sample if there is any.

Answer (score 5):

### Troubleshooting:

Do you see something like this in your console?

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://adobeid-na1.services.adobe.com/ims/check/v4/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://your.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Then you likely do not have a valid SSL certificate.

---

### From the documentation:

From Adobe's [Getting started with the Creative SDK for Web](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/web/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html):

> If you get an XMLHttpRequest error due to
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', there is likely an issue with your SSL
>   setup (as noted in the “Prerequisites” section of this guide, SSL is
>   required).

And here's what's stated in the Prerequisites section [**emphasis added**]:

> **Prerequisites**
>
> 1. Before you can work with the Creative SDK, you must register your
>      application and get Client ID (API Key) and Client Secret values. For
>      details, see the “Registering Your Application” section of this guide.
> 2. The following software is required:
>
>    - Supported browsers: Chrome 53+, Safari 9+, Firefox 45+, Edge, IE11+
>    - **SSL required: Your site must support SSL on any page that integrates    the Creative SDK.**

---

### Possible Solution:

If you're testing on your dev machine from `localhost`, then you'll need to modify your `hosts` file and setup your own domain mapped to 127.0.0.1, then you'll need to configure a self-signed certificate on your server.

You may also want to check out [How to use locally](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/web-getting-started-samples/tree/master/getting-started/code#how-to-use-locally) (from their Github repo) which has this wonderful gem:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout server.pem -out server.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

**Helpful Resources:**

- [How do you use https / SSL on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874390/how-do-you-use-https-ssl-on-localhost)
- [How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost)

---

## How I got it working:

### 1. Adobe I/O Setup:

Here's how my test application was configured on Adobe I/O:

[image]

### 2. Local HTTP Server (SSL)

At the root, to create a self-signed cert, run:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout server.pem -out server.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

Then, I've setup a simple python server that uses that self-signed cert `server.pem` created above:

```
# ./start.py
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='server.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Started my server

```
python ./start.py
```

### 3. Hit https://localhost:4443

**Important Note:** You will get an 200 response with the following payload: `{"error":"invalid_credentials"}` on that second call.  As long as you don't get a console error, your web app is ready.

As per the documentation, I added a button with `csdk-login` to test the User Auth UI api.

---

### 4. Fully working code

**File structure:**

```
/app
├── config.js <-- my clientId config
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── server.pem <-- my self-signed cert
└── start.py  <-- my server
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Technophobia: SDK Getting Started</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Adobe Creative SDK</h1>
    <p>Look at the console</p>

    <button id="csdk-login">Log in to Creative Cloud</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn-creativesdk.adobe.io/v1/csdk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
/* 1) Initialize the AdobeCreativeSDK object */
AdobeCreativeSDK.init({
    /* 2) Add your Client ID (API Key) */
    clientID: CONFIG.CSDK_CLIENT_ID, //
    API: ["Asset"],
    onError: function(error) {
        /* 3) Handle any global or config errors */
        if (error.type === AdobeCreativeSDK.ErrorTypes.AUTHENTICATION) {
            console.log('You must be logged in to use the Creative SDK');
        } else if (error.type === AdobeCreativeSDK.ErrorTypes.GLOBAL_CONFIGURATION) {
            console.log('Please check your configuration');
        } else if (error.type === AdobeCreativeSDK.ErrorTypes.SERVER_ERROR) {
            console.log('Oops, something went wrong');
        }
    }
});

/* 1) Add a click handler to a button that calls a helper function */
document.getElementById("csdk-login").addEventListener('click', handleCsdkLogin, false);

/* 2) Make a helper function */
function handleCsdkLogin() {

    /* 3) Get auth status */
    AdobeCreativeSDK.getAuthStatus(function(csdkAuth) {

        /* 4) Handle auth based on status */
        if (csdkAuth.isAuthorized) {
            // The user is logged in and has authorized your site.
            console.log('Logged in!');
        } else {
            // Trigger a login
            AdobeCreativeSDK.login(handleCsdkLogin);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I do get the  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error but my SSL certificate is valid (I've checked it with https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) the certificate should be trusted by all major web browsers (all the correct intermediate certificates are installed), the certificate will expire in 281 days and my hostname is correctly listed in the certificate.

Comment: By the way, our SSL certificate is issued by Amazon.

Comment: Following the instructions on "How to use locally" and running my application on a simple Python server, I was able to suppress that error and continue testing my application.  I'll update the answer with some more (hopefully useful) information for you.

Comment: @RaananAvidor I update the answer - have a look at how I got mine working, perhaps it will help you with your issue(s).

Comment: Thank you very much. You have earned your bounty :)