# How can i run PWA when i publish application in Local IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I published the progressive web application in local IIS and now i access this application in another network machine using IIS hosted machine IP and Alias Name like (xxx.xxx.x.xxx/aliasname). Also I can access the application but application can not react as progressive web application behavior and also serviceworker can not register!!
So that Issue, What can i do?

Comment: I'm unsure if this is what you are asking for, you need to add webmanifest as a MIME type in IIS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566446/how-can-i-have-iis-properly-serve-webmanifest-files-on-my-web-site

Comment: Are you talking about IIS Express? If yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/how-to-enable-external-request-in-iis-express

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help. I talking about that when i publish my app in my local machine IIS. Now my machine is connected with local network, so i can use the application link using with ip (192.192.1.192/AliasName) in other machine which is also under local network. Now in other machine, Service worker can not registered that's why progressive web application can not comes into picture. For sure, Progressive Web Apps required SSL certificate, but for local testing, how can i use Progressive Web application without using localhost( Here i replace localhost to machineip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service worker API will never work without https (secure) connection. [Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/get-started#https).

See if you can able to set up your local instance in https protocol as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874390/how-do-you-use-https-ssl-on-localhost).